# rgbdslam and octomap

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am using ros fuerte on ubuntu 12.04 and have few questions:

1. Does anyone know how rgbdslam and octomap cooperates?
2. Is there any possibility to manipulate with map created by rgbdslam?
3. Is there a possibility to build octomap with octomap_server out of rgbdslam algorithm and visualise it?
4. Is there possibility to reduce the size of created map? for example to 1-2 meters around robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127581/rgbdslam-and-octomap/) by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

1. There are two possibilities:  (a)  Have rgbdslam send out the clouds+tf transformations and let the octomap_server listen or (b) Use the GUI of rgbdslam to save the map as an octomap (no need to run octomap_server)
2. No. You can manipulate the octomap using octovis - though this functionality is quite limited.
3. See 1.
4. You can (a) set the parameter 'maximum_depth" for rgbdslam (though this will also limit the use of faraway visual features during mapping)
   or (b) set the max_sensor_range parameter for the octomap_server (only affects map rendering)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-02-16**:
Do I need an experimental version of octomap- when I save the map with:  rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver file.ot   I see only a blue cube but if I save it with rgbdslam GUI I can see map. I am working with rosbag files (rgbd_dataset_freiburg2_pioneer_360.bag).

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-02-19**:
The blue cube means no data. So I guess that the data you send from rgbdslam does not arrive at the octomap server.

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-12-11**:
When i use the GUI to save the octomap it saves as .pcd file. Furthermore, when i try to visualize the point cloud i got an error: No points to read. Like you said, i guess the data sent from rgbdslam did not arrive to octomap server. Do you know how can i fix that ?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2015-01-12**:
I do not have this problem. Can you just try to rename the file to .ot?

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2015-01-12**:
Yes, i tried! Using octovis to visualize, the file is empty

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2015-01-14**:
To clarify, I meant the file saved from the GUI. What is the file size? Any output on the terminal concerning the saving of the octomap?

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2018-02-14**:
Hey Felix!!!
Can you expand more on point 1 and yaa I am also getting empty file through GUI. What to do